# Mod_Rewrite rule from htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm new at apache rewrite rules and I'm trying to make a rule that do this, from:

http://anydomain/anyfolder/anyfile.Extension?anyquery

To:

http://anydomain/anyfolder-anyfileWithoutExtension?anyquery

What I did was:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)-([^/]+)?$ $1/$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But it doesnt work as it should
Any ideas?

Comment: I want to go from: **www.domail.com/folder/page.php?var=0** to **www.domain.com/folder-page?var=0**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect

- http://anydomain/anyfolder/anyfile.Extension?anyquery

To:

- http://anydomain/anyfolder-anyfileWithoutExtension?anyquery

try the following rule in root/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/(.+)\..+$ /$1/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: this doesnt work 
Maybe I wasnt clear enough:
I want to go from: **www.domail.com/folder/page.php?var=0** to **www.domain.com/folder-page?var=0**